# The scale of Redshift Decimal datatype cannot greater than 11?

Tags: amazon-redshift

According the [official doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html#r_Numeric_types201-decimal-or-numeric-type), the maximum scale should be 37. However, I found that if I create an column likes Decimal(38,12), then the scale will be set to -4 actually. In other words, the actual available scale is 0~11, which is conflict with the doc.

So, I want to know that if there is any special when decimal precision is 38? Or this is doc bug?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an JDBC Driver bug. Everything would be normal if do query using psql.